# Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

I touched on this quite a bit in our [recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), but I want to reiterate it again.

***It's fine if users post bug reports, requests for support or feature requests here on MSO, there's no need to close them as off-topic. Please, don't do that, it's off-putting and rude.***

On *every other site in the network*, our guidance for *years* has been, "Just post on your child meta site, if it needs to get more attention on the network meta <sup><sub>(at that time, MSO)</sub></sup>, we'll handle moving it over for you."

Stack Overflow is now *no different* than any site in our network in this respect, this is no different than any other self-contained child meta site. If Stack Overflow participants are more comfortable reporting bugs or asking for features here, worry *more* about engaging them in discussion or support than what bucket might fit their question best.

As time goes on, and we get a better grasp of specific contexts in certain kinds of reports and requests that result in us migrating questions over, we can then *possibly* think about establishing migration paths along with some concrete guidance. Until then - please folks, you've *got* the venue for discussions all to yourselves again - take advantage of it and be *jealous* of the discussions that start here. Don't willingly let them go somewhere else.

Comment: While closing them as off topic would be stupid; if they aren't migrated surely it's going to become a nightmare going forward; 100+ unlinked feature requests for every feature, 100+ unlinked bug reports. Possibly this requires a cross-meta closure feature (Edit; the blog post suggests migrations will occure, which is good)

Comment: Hm?  SE sees all bug reports, across all metas.

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them/250156#250156), @Richard.

Comment: @Shog9 bugs don't really need community involvement so (other than for the poster) there's not too much duplication, doesn't solve feature requests though

Comment: Feature-requests *do* need community involvement, @Richard. And that should start with the community you're actively a part of.

Comment: @Shog9 I think you've read that the wrong way round,  thats the opposite of what I was saying. I am saying feature requests need huge community involvement,  and so the same arguments will be put forward and discussed a hundred times (rather than once and then everyone agreeing with an existing position or creating a new unique one)

Comment: And? Do you honestly think we'd be doing anyone any favors by migrating every new "folks should be forced to comment when downvoting" post to MSE? That's just cruelty at this point, and the same principle applies, albeit to a lesser extent, to the vast majority of requests. All politics is local, @Richard...

Comment: @Shog9 probably the most useful would be to migrate the first one and cross-meta close as duplicate the rest (currently impossible). This avoids someone having to type out the same tired arguments for/against the idea and if they have a unique position they can put it where it's most likely to be viewed (I'm pretty much repeating the arguments for why we close duplicates at all at this point)

Comment: Dammit, @Richard. Get rid of this idea that the purpose of Meta is to police and slap down everyone possible at every turn. *Every* site is going to have some of the same discussions at one point or another, *and that's OK!* Without this "repetition", folks will never [internalize the reasoning behind things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915) - and without that, we're doomed. Look at MSE as an archive of information useful when conducting these discussions, **not as an excuse to shut them down!**

Comment: @Shog9 where did I say police, slap down or shut down?  I said "draw into the debate". I'm actually looking at this from a "wasting the potential of MSE" point of view

Comment: Don't get into a pointless semantics argument with me, @Richard. If you honestly think cross-site dup-closing is a good idea, post that as a request and see how that fares...

Comment: @Shog9 I was actually planning on it (probably once the whole split calms down). I anticipate an interesting rebuttal from yourself

Comment: Fortunately, you don't have to wait to find out what that might be - just [draw on that rich archive...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates/16708#16708)

Comment: @Shog9 Related and interesting (and not without support) but different because a [network-wide] feature request cannot exist in isolation from the other sites in the network. Regardless, I'll stop now as this is going a little off topic

Comment: @Shog9 Someone got there before me [Could we allow child Meta questions to be closed as duplicates of Meta.SE ones?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229870/could-we-allow-child-meta-questions-to-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-meta-se-ones)

Comment: Perhaps `s/jealous/proud/`?

Comment: @shog9 *gives hug*

Comment: @shog9 - this goes to the idea of these "child" SE sites being stand-alone communities, no?  If so it would make sense to me that their meta posts would *not* need to be consolidated / closed as dup, as you argue.

Comment: Correct, @Adam. While it's always nice to see folks with a broad range of interests participating on multiple sites, this is not a realistic expectation for the majority of folks; best to keep support and discussion localized when possible, both as a courtesy to the folks involved and to help distribute the load as we grow.

Answer (score 75):

It might help y'all to know that we can and do have tooling to track bugs across the entire network without the need for unproductive migration:

[image: the big list of bugs]

If a report is properly tagged, *we will see it no matter where it sits* - if you want to be helpful, then adding cross-links between duplicate or related reports on multiple sites does save us time, but even without that we'll eventually find them.

Comment: Is that number 3446 open bugs across the network?

Comment: Yeah. Don't laugh - I'll bet your bugs database is backlogged too.

Comment: Oh, I won't laugh and yes it is...

Comment: "*S/AC*" - You assign a Strength and Armor Class to bug reports?  What a bunch of nerds.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I assume those are Score/Answer Count. `:)`

Comment: @Shog9 all of those bugs will be fixed in 6 to 8 weeks anyway, right?

Comment: Totally. Like half of them are just misplaced "s"s anyway.

Comment: For us mere mortals, the [Filtered Questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters) page can serve as [a crude replacement](http://stackexchange.com/filters/117163/bugs-and-features-on-site-metas) of such a tool.  (Note that this filter does *not* include MSE, since it would drown out all the other metas; it also currently does not include MSO, although it perhaps should.)

Comment: 3446 bugs? Is this why no one is addressing my heart-wrenching issue of [questions that advertise themselves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93138/147335)?

Comment: Hey, you posted a picture of Oded's house - you sure he's okay with that?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen [Here](http://stackexchange.com/filters/245531/bugs-frs)'s a filter that includes MSE and MSO as well. As you see, MSE doesn't dominate the list.