# How to format code after item list?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

My text contains a few item list and a code block, but I am really crazy when formatting the code, each time I try to format it, it was align to the item list, my work around was put an dot(.) between the list and the code block, any good way?

original text:

> first line
>
> seconds line
>
> third line
>
> int main(void) {
>       return 0; }

first, I click the numbered list button to format the first 3 lines, I got the following result:

1. first line    seconds line    third line

Then I manually separated the 2nd and 3rd lines to make it like this

1. first line
2. seconds line
3. third line

From here, I tried lots of way to format the code, I always got this

1. first line
2. seconds line
3. third line

   int main(void) 
   {
      return 0; 
   }

Finally, I put a dot between the list and the code block, too ugly, but works.

1. first line
2. seconds line
3. third line

.

```
int main(void) 
{
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: FYI If you want the line but not the dot you can use `<br>` but Mat's solution avoids the newline altogether (which is likely what you want

Comment: This question is not *Stack Overflow specific* and already [have an answer in here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: @FallenAngel: So? This is still an issue Stack Overflow users will come across. Meta.SE is a different site, the central government of all Stack Exchange sites. Asking questions like these here is **fine**; this is the local government, we can proxy for the central site just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, this is a duplicate. The very same question in both *Main Meta* and *SO Meta*. It sounds better to me to have this question in Main and close this as duplicate since this is a general issue. Having the same question on separate Meta Sites is not good if it is a general one.

Comment: @FallenAngel: No, really, that's *fine*. The alternative is that we send people over in droves as everything here is closed as OT, again and again and again. and Stack Overflow does have unique tweaks to the software that other sites don't have, so answers here *can* and *do* differ.

Comment: @FallenAngel: also see [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152) and [Meta hasn't changed at all](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251375)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahhh I see. I missed those topics. Close vote retracted (:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. first line

   ```
   // code for the first item, indented with 8 spaces
   ```
2. second line

   ```
   // code for the second item
   ```
3. third line

   ```
   // code for the third item
   ```

```
//code not in the list
int main(void) 
{
   return 0; 
}
```

To avoid your empty line with a `.`, use a `<!-- -->` comment thingy.