# All-new profile: hovering over next badge remains mute

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In the new profile, there is a badge section in which progress for the next badge is displayed.  However, in contrast to the traditional hovering behaviour of badges which showed the actual purpose of the badge, nothing is shown for the next badge.

Request: Make the next badge hoverable with the traditional description.

Comment: Just came to comment on that myself. Seems to be missing its 'hot tip'.

Comment: I agree this would be nice. But, fwiw, clicking on it does give some detail (in case you didn't realize it). Also, this may do better here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list but not sure. There's a long list. Clicking on it also gives a "Go get it" button so there's that.

Comment: Please consider adding this to [the master feedback list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

Comment: Please report issues and comments with the new profiles here on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253484/174278)

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen No, they're perfectly *on-topic*. [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen hichris is correct. There are enough moderators present on Meta.SO at any given time that if we think something needs to be migrated to Meta.SE, we'll migrate it; we don't want users getting bounced around unnecessarily.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sounds good. Just wanted to make sure things are getting seen, and since there was a master thread on MSE, I wanted to make sure the problems got posted there too!

Comment: Is someone going mark this as [meta-tag:status-declined] as it is declined on MSE as @false linked to?

Answer (score 1):

The feature that you are requesting is already present in the new profile.

You can see other badge progress here:

- go to Activity tab
- See the next badge progress, there is a icon of setting just after badge, click on it.
- You will see a popup as below in the image:

[image]

You can search the badge by name of you can move by tab for other badge progress.

Hope this will help you.

**EDITED**

You can get the information about the badge progress after clicking on that badge.

Comment: But... tooltips!

Comment: You can get the information about the badge progress after clicking on that badge.