# Favorites in new profile: box not wide enough for "answers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[Note: I checked a few other sites, but this appears to be affecting SO and MSO exclusively.]

On the new profile, go to Activity -> favorites. The text in "answers" blocks is overflowing the area. See here:

[image: text overflowing answers blocks]

Comment: It's also been reported here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253458/285344

Comment: Please report issues and comments with the new profiles here on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: This is on-topic, see [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).