# Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

While browsing through some user profiles in the new profile page, I came across this description:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

I do not understand where this description comes from. Is it shown, because the corresponding users did not update their "about me" area? Or is it some privacy feature that I am missing?

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>EDIT: As per the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290394/apparently-this-user-prefers-to-keep-an-air-of-mystery-about-them#comment178196_290394) by [hichris123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2581872/hichris123), I once again believe this question belongs here.</sup>

Comment: MSE dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251810/245360

Comment: Voting to close as this is not an SO specific topic.

Comment: Yeah, that's becuase they did not update their "about me" area

Comment: This is an on-topic discussion, see [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them). That goes for discussions about verbiage, too.

Comment: True, but what is the point in the duplicate discussion. If you want to discuss this, go to MSE. Then all can benefit.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Right, agree. Just can't agree with `Voting to close as this is not an SO specific topic`. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a cross-meta duplicate, as seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251810/245360) on MSE.

The text you see is just a placeholder when the 'about me' is empty. The 'about me' can be edited by the owner of the profile.

(If you don't want to see that text in your profile, put a space in your profile and it will be gone)