# Impossible vote count

Tags: support

So when I just scrolled by my vote count I noticed something odd:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

As you can see here I voted 26 times this month, however I also voted 41 times this week. How is this possible? How can I have voted more times in a week of the month than in the whole month?

By the way I also checked the vote stats on the acounts of some other users and this applies to all the users that I have checked.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something very Obvious?

Comment: Date calculations on SO soo hard.(would like to have that dupe ;-) )

Comment: So "per month" restarts at the 1st of each month *but* "per week" means "the past 7 days"?

Comment: @Jongware No, the month always starts on the 1st, and the week always starts on Sunday, and the day always starts at midnight.

Comment: @animuson: that's fair. Midnight, where?

Comment: @Jongware: Midnight UTC

Comment: The real question is, what would your stats say on 15 October 1582?

Comment: The fact that the week starts on Sunday is absolutely *non*-obvious. AFAIK in Europe weeks start on *Monday* and Sunday is the *last* day of the week. Is this mentioned anywhere in an help page?

Comment: @Bakuriu AFAIK the first day of the week according to ISO is Monday, so probably not only Europe ;)

Comment: Some weeks contain two months...

Comment: @Stephen: SO is not meant to be international, so ISO is not necessarily an argument. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87251/use-m-for-million-instead-of-m for another example

Comment: @Thomas: I didn't mean to use it as an argument pro or con (I am very comfortable with Sunday as first day of the week due to my upbringing). I just wanted to point out that Monday as the first day of the week is probably not only in Europe the norm.

Comment: @Yakk: +1 for the changeover from Julian to Gregorian calendars

Comment: @Bakuriu If they want to add hover text that makes the range clear, cool, but the team will will be deterred from making UI changes if the bar for each change is detailed documentation in the help section. If this deserves a help page, then surely the "M" vs "m" thing does, too. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295868/why-does-the-people-reached-counter-use-a-lowercase-m-for-millions And doubtless many other things as well.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> *"Or am I missing something very Obvious?"*

Yes! That refers to the last month (May), rather the last week, since *last week* isn't completed for the actual month (June) as the last week for the current month isn't yet completed at the sixth day.

Uniform time calculations at Stack Overflow are based on UTC, if I remember correctly.

Comment: How does it make sense to have "month" refer to last month, but week refer to this week and "day" refer to this day? That's nonsense. All of them should refer to the present time unit: this month, this week, today.

Comment: @Lundin or the previous time unit - last month, last week, yesterday.

Comment: @Lundin That would be another great meta question!

Answer (score 7):

*Moving my comment to an answer...*

> That refers to the last month (May), rather the last week, since last
>   week isn't completed for the actual month (June) as the last week for
>   the current month isn't yet completed at the sixth day.

I believe the above confusion could be avoided by doing something as simple as:

- **day:** past `24` hours
- **week:** past `24 * 7` hours
- **month:** past `24 * (365 / 12)` hours

These stats still can be cached and updated at UTC midnight (or whatever SO currently does) without any issues. The information will be more up-to-date and there will be no "how the heck did they get that number" situations like the OP.