# Migrate [ios-app] and [android-app]

Tags: discussion, meta, migration

The questions in tags [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) (26 Questions) and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) (50 Questions) should in almost all cases be migrated to MSE.

Rather than flagging all questions can a mod make these migrations? *[Where appropriate].*

Is there a way we can make it clearer for new questions that app related question should be asked on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

No, they should not be migrated. Users are not required to go to MSE, they are free to post on a child Meta if they prefer to do so.

Source: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Comment: Thanks Stijn, I believe this maybe different for the apps as everything I have seen always asks that app related questions are asked on MSE. in actual fact the except from both tags says "Questions about the iOS/Andriod app should be asked on Meta Stack Exchange."

Comment: You're right, the tags do say that. It was added by @animuson, perhaps we could get his input on this.