# My winter hat won't stay put

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, winter-bash

When viewing my profile with the iOS application my winter hat doesn't stay attached to my avatar. It's static in the top left corner as I continue to scroll through my profile. Example:

[image: go home hat, you're drunk]

Using the application on an iPhone 6S running iOS 9.2.

Comment: Maybe an Apple knocked it out of place.

Comment: [Maybe some glue would help.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IYOvUs-ul4)

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [Hat scrolls with page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270812/hat-scrolls-with-page). (iOS app bugs should be reported on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com), anyway.)

Comment: maybe because that's not a hat, it's just a headset ;)

Comment: @rickster ah, my mistake. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @rickster: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them). Please don't tell users that they posted the bug in the wrong place if it is on *a* Meta. If it needs to be moved, it will be moved.

Comment: ah, my bad. well, it's fixed (soon?) anyway.

Comment: Stay out of the wind and storms *(bad pun)*.

Comment: And my hat immediately turned me into Skrillex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be solved in 1.4.2.3, which may roll out before or after Winter Bash is over.

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270812/hat-scrolls-with-page/270867), the problem is that the hats are in a separate overlay view and the logic to keep them in sync was placed in an `#ifdef DEBUG`.