# How do I get started on Meta Stack Exchange without reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

This is my state of rep after signing up to Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Reputation]

Ok, so how do I earn rep on Meta? Post a question, you say?

[image: Post a question]

> You must have at least 2 reputation to ask a question.

Well, answer a question then?

[image: Post an answer]

> You must have at least 2 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange to answer a question on Meta.

Comments don't bring any rep, but even if they did, you may have guessed it by now — I need rep to comment too...

So, what the hell am I supposed to do if I want to use Meta? Post on some of the other sites, and wait for a moderator to move the post?

Comment: I would guess it would be rather rare that someone has a stack exchange account *only* on a meta site, and when you link your existing account to a new site, like meta, you're supposed to get 100 rep out of the box, if I'm not mistaken. Did you sign up for a completely new account or did you use your existing stack exchange network account when you signed up for meta?

Comment: There was this chicken...

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen - I think I used my emal to sign up to Stack Overflow, then I added an OpenId of launchpad to it, and I think I when I went to Meta, it noticed the OpenId and it offered me "Join this Community", and so I entered via that... Obviously, I didn't get a 100 out of the box. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, that should be the Meta account associated to this one...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen did it cross the road and, if so, why?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the +100 points, guys, I'm really happy I can comment now `:)` I guess the problem is solved for me now ... Thanks again!

Comment: However, to answer this, if you edit any post and it gets approved, you get +2 rep. So one should fix a post which has typos or bad English and get the +2 rep.

Comment: Excellent @Sunshine - that is exactly what I would have used! Feel free to post that as an answer... Btw I read somewhere there is some sort of a queue that automatically shows you "low quality posts", is there a way for a 1-point user to access that?

Comment: @sdbbs why do you want to go dumpster-diving?

Comment: @MartinJames - I'm not sure what do you mean "dumpster-diving", is it because edits give you just 2 pts rep? I guess, because I cannot really count on posting questions and answers to build up the first 10-20 pts of rep fast, while with edits, it would be easier, in the sense that correcting grammar and such for me is more mechanical, actual coding Q's and A's do require a bit of creativity and involvement with the problem... Cheers!

Comment: THis question belongs on [meta.se], not here.

Comment: This was pretty funny but also scary to see...again the rules should be relaxed in general on the SE sites, or we have unhappy customers.  This is a common theme and the people that don't notice it are the people who have been here too long to notice it.  (They have too much rep).

Comment: @Deduplicator it may belong on MSE... but when the question is "I CAN'T POST ON MSE"... that's a pretty moot point to make, no?

Comment: @Patrice That's the joke.

Comment: @Ajedi32 not 100% sure it is. People on meta can be EXTREMELY pedantic, up to posting that kind of inanity. If this is indeed a joke, then I guess it doesn't translate very well to the written form :P

Comment: Can this question be migrated to Meta Stack Exchange even if the author hasn't the right to post question there?

Comment: @Lasse you would only get the Association Bonus if you reach 200 reputation on one site.

Comment: I realized that after reading the comments.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The rep requirement for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (aka MSE) posts was [temporarily raised to 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse/278689#278689) due to a [flood of off-topic questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278683/statistics-regarding-users-who-recently-flooded-mse-with-blatantly-off-topic-deb) from users who didn't know (or didn't care) about the purpose of MSE, or thought they were on a different site.

The increased minimum was supposed to only be for a day or 2, but as soon as it was lowered, the [flood of off-topic posts returned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse/278689#comment903969_278689), so the minimum was put back at 2 and has remained there.  It is unfortunate that new users are cut off from using MSE, but when you have more off-topic new questions than on-topic new questions, it is a problem and needed to be addressed.

So for someone with a brand new account on MSE, there are really only 2 ways to get started:

- By far the easiest is to edit a single post and get +2 rep (make sure it is a good edit though).
- Earn 200 rep on any other Stack Exchange site.  When you do that, you will earn the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), which will automatically grant you +100 rep on all Stack Exchange sites, including new accounts you open.  This includes MSE.

There is a 3rd method, but it is not really something you can do on your own. You could get really really really lucky to have an excellent MSE on-topic post migrated from a main site to the child meta site to Meta Stack Exchange (although I would **strongly** caution you from actually trying this, because it is more likely you are going to get your question downvoted, closed, and deleted).

Of course, if you have sufficient rep to post on a child meta site, such as MSO, you can always post there.  In fact, the Community team has even indicated that in [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).  So if you have 5 rep on a site, you can post on that site's meta and it will be migrated if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that really explains the mechanism - wish I had read this post earlier!

Comment: @sdbbs as [Deduplicator mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323444/how-do-i-get-started-on-meta-stack-exchange-without-reputation#comment346315_323444) this is better for MSE so you might actually get the 3rd path (and you should get all of the rep associated with the votes on this post there)

Comment: Thanks @psubsee2003 - I just flagged the post for moving, hope its OK...

Comment: Method 3 is how this question got here in the first place.

Comment: @OrangeDog I know, why it mentioned it or I wouldn't have every suggested it as an option.

Comment: This should be shown in a banner on the site. It is unacceptable to confuse "real" users in this manner while hiding away the reason in some Meta.SE answer somewhere that they're never going to find. What an abysmal user experience.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [they did inform users with a yellow banner on top, but hey, who expects users to read before asking](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwhs.png)

Comment: @Braiam: nonono, a banner about the rep limit for _everything_ being raised to 2 and a link to why. Contributions from new users have been effectively completely disabled and new users are not being told _why_. That's absurd.

Comment: Hmm... Activity has ought to have slowed down, and it really should be reversed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get that it would be nice if there were a little more info somewhere, but frankly, this isn't *that* bad. Do comment rep requirements get a banner that links to why? Do regular metas get a link to why? The user *does* get a banner about the 2 rep requirement. If they can't figure out that it probably has to do with moderation (keeping low quality stuff that wastes everyone's time out), they have a *lot* to learn about how StackExchange works in general, and they're going to have to pick that up as they go. It's not "abysmal"; it's just a bit less than perfect.

Comment: @jpmc26: They're not going to pick anything up when they're literally banned from contributing in any way whatsoever, for no apparent reason. I can't believe I'm saying this of all people but, in this matter, SE needs to be far more considerate of those who don't take this site's model for granted, and go back to first principles: this is, objectively, a terrible user experience.