# Where can I go to figure out which SE site to ask on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

If I have a question that I want answered and I am unsure which category it falls under, how will I know where to ask it?

Obviously, posting on a random site is not a good solution.

Comment: See the [list of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). Use your common sense, `/help/on-topic` and `/help/dont-ask` to choose the appropriate site for your question.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can ask over at meta.stackexchange.com where your question should go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of questions belong on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275082/what-kind-of-questions-belong-on-stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: @gnat that post seems specific to that post in question.  Not sure I agree with the duplicate,

Answer (score 3):

There are really a couple of options.

First, you should try to find it yourself.  You can browse the list of sites on [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).  There are several tabs to help you filter the list to a general topic, and while you browse list of sites, be sure to read the general scope of the site.  Don't just assume by the name of the site that your question is acceptable.

Once you have a list of potential sites (there are some sites with overlapping scopes, so you may find more than one that potentially fits your question), you should visit each site's help center and look at 2 specific pages in the help center:

- ***/help/on-topic*** - this will tell you what is on topic on the site.  Sometimes this can be very general on beta sites as the on-topic scope has not been fully finalized.
- ***/help/dont-ask*** - this will tell you what kinds of questions not to ask.  Again this can be very general on some sites, but many will have specific rules to help guide you.

After reading the help center, if you still aren't sure, try asking on that site's meta site (meta.____.stackexchange.com). You do need 5 rep on the site to post there, so if you haven't earned the association bonus or don't have 5 rep on the site in question, this step may not be possible.

When asking, there are a couple of very specific details you should include:

1. What is your question about.  What topic or topics do you want to ask about.  But try to be specific.  Don't just say "I have a programming quesiton, where can I ask it".
2. What is your question (briefly).  This can be extremely important as the topic of the question does not always tell the users enough about your question to make an good recommendation.

If you have absolutely no clue where to look and need advice (or you don't have 5 rep to post on the child-meta), then you can go to [Meta.StackExhange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and ask a question using the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag.  Be sure to provide the same level of detail mentioned above.  Plus, if you have a couple of sites you are debating between, please identify them and explain why you aren't sure which one to use.

However, if you get a recommendation on MSE, you should still go back to that site's help center and/or meta site to confirm.  While you usually will get good advice on MSE as to which site fits your topic, no one is an expert on the scope of every single site.  The site itself (not the community on MSE) is the final determining factor in what is on or off topic on their own site.

There is one additional caveat.  As of this writing, to post on Meta.SE you need a minimum of 2 reputation on that site.  This is a "temporary" restriction related to a flood of off-topic posts on that site.  If you do not meet that reputation requirement, you can find some solutions in my answer to [How do I get started on Meta Stack Exchange without reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323444/how-do-i-get-started-on-meta-stack-exchange-without-reputation/323453#323453).