# Challenge idea (What is the maximum number of backslashes required to mean one backslash?)

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Here's an idea I have for a question, but I don't think it quite fits codegolf, and I don't think it quite fits stackOverflow, but it is kinda relevant to both.

I'm a little worried about posting it, though, so can I get some feedback on:

1. Which site to post it on?
2. How to improve it so that it doesn't become an endless loop?

> If you want to use a regex to look for a backslash, you have to escape
>   that backslash, so that the character after it isn't escaped instead.
>   But if you then have to store this regex in a string (in a c-style
>   language, for instance), you need to double the number of backslashes,
>   so that a regex string to match \stuff\ would need to be
>   "\\\\stu(f+)\\\\" (and I had to further double the backslashes
>   to post it in StackOverflow, but that isn't executable so doesn't
>   count).
>
> In your answer, explain the language and the (reasonable) situation,
>   from either real or made-up business needs, and the answer with the
>   most backslashes (per final, output backslash) will get upvoted
>   (permanently) and accepted (until a better one comes along). If using
>   AutoHotKey or another language that has a different escape character
>   (for instance, `), then instances of that character will count
>   instead of backslashes.
>
> This question is not how many backslashes *could* you use in some
>   esoteric code-golfing language to eventually calculate to a backslash,
>   otherwise I don't think there would be an upper limit. This instead is
>   about feasible scenarios that **force** you to use a lot of
>   backslashes.

Comment: The question is certainly out of scope for Stack Overflow, that's for sure. We can't speak for other sites. Ask on *their* Meta sites.

Comment: [Meta is Murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/).

Comment: The down votes might be disagreement that the question is related to SO but I'm guessing a few might be because your question title doesn't make it clear that you're asking where to post this question as opposed to trying to get it answered on Meta itself. (I only make this suggestion because that's what I initially thought.)

Comment: @NH.: This *is* a safe place. You don't suffer any penalties from downvotes (nor do you gain any reputation from upvotes). As such votes *don't hurt you*, they are used freely to express (dis)agreement, or how people feel about the suitability of the post, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I go to figure out which SE site to ask on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323543/where-can-i-go-to-figure-out-which-se-site-to-ask-on)

Answer (score 6):

It isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow. "Challenge" questions aren't suitable here.

However, I/we cannot speak to the policies of other sites. You'll need to ask on their Meta.

Maybe re-consider [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)? It isn't a golfing exercise, really, but it does seem like a puzzle of sorts. Their Meta is [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, is cross-posting on metas allowed?

Comment: As always, tailor your question to the site you're asking it on. Same goes for Metas. Indicating that you've read the site's guidelines and How To Ask page will go a long way. @NH.

Comment: It is PPCG not CGPP

Comment: I wouldn't consider this question on topic at PPCG either. This isn't "write some code that does X" with an objective winning criteria.

Comment: @Draco18s "Write some code that uses as many backslashes as possible to represent one backslash" with an objective winning criteria being the largest number of backslashes used to represent a single backslash doesn't qualify as "write some code that does X" with an objective winning criteria? Keep in mind that I don't visit PPCG often, but that doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @TinyGiant That would likely fall under the tag [code-bowling] which has virtually no good questions (most end up closed). It might get accepted, but honestly, probably not, due to things like `eval(...)` where you'd need more back slashes for each level of eval and you can have arbitrarily many levels of eval.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation. @Draco18s

Answer (score 4):

Only speaking to Stack Overflow, this definitely isn't on-topic.  The reason for this is that a developer who needs to write regex *and* escape backslash will do so according to the constraints of their language.

I'm not convinced it's on-topic anywhere else either, since it's so broad and so open-ended.  There's no way to define a concrete "answer" since regex varies across languages.