# Your vote will count once you earn 125 rep, does this work?

Tags: discussion, support

Does this actually work?

When I try to down-vote this is what I get:

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 125 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

My question is: Does SO actually store all my down-votes and show all of them once I become over 125reps?

Comment: As this is a system wide feature, shouldn't that rather be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for bugs that is certainly not the case and I think it shouldn't be the case for users that only participate on SO. It would be probably a dupe there as well.

Comment: Okay so that message is wrong.

Comment: I recall a discussion before about the wording but that didn't lead to a change, AFAIK. .. found it on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591/158100), answered by Shog9 himself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the general message for everything is post on whichever meta you want.  Nothing "has" to be on MSE (source: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Comment: @afucfunc I agree that the wording you quoted is misleading since it suggests your previous "non-votes" will automatically change.  Perhaps a new feature request to change the wording is more appropriate

Comment: can I edit this to be feature req?

Comment: @afucfunc it's better to just ask a new question.

Comment: @afucfunc question asked for you: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326060/2142994