# Why do some MSE discussions link to MSO for an answer?

Tags: discussion

<sub>MSE = Meta Stack Exchange; MSO = Stack Overflow Meta</sub>

For some SE issues I face, I dig up relevant MSE posts and many of those posts contain relevant links for reference or further reading.

A thing I find odd is: The linked posts discuss issues affecting the entire Stack Exchange network and yet are hosted on MSO, instead of MSE.

**Why is that?**

Example: *[Voting with less than 125 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280779/309993)* from MSE links to *[Change the wording of “Thank you for your feedback…”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326060/5832912)* on MSO.

Comment: Could you give some example links please? Unfortunately we have no method to auto-migrate such question to Meta SE.

Comment: How many SO users, as a percentage, do you think have any idea about MSE? vs, how many know about MSO?

Comment: @Oded What do you mean? The linked meta SO post is at least 17 days old. It's a feature-request for entire SE, and now it's even status-completed. Why didn't anyone migrate it to meta SE yet?

Comment: Why should it be migrated there?

Comment: It is also important to know that the age of the post is a factor.  Before April 2014, MSO and MSE were a single site (called Meta.StackOverflow).  They were then split into the separate sites that exist today.  But only current relavant posts about MSO were moved to the current MSO.  The older posts were left alone since migrating them didn't seem to serve a purposes.  But some important material was migrated regardless of age, so you end up with some MSO posts linking to MSE posts and the other way around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Users are not required to post on MSE any time anything they discuss might have implications for other sites.

Users are encouraged to post on the meta site on the site(s) they are active participants in, so that they can discuss ideas among their community.

While it's certainly *acceptable* to post on MSE if you know that the question isn't necessarily related to just your community, you certainly aren't required to.  Additionally, discussions about a topic or proposal among a community won't be migrated to MSE just because they might impact other communities.  Someone may create a new question on MSE, if they feel that it's important for members of other communities to weigh in, at their own discretion, but discussions among a community will stay in that community's meta.

Comment: Ser, for further reading, can you link to any official ruling like this?

Comment: @NVZ It's been covered in a few different places, the one I can easily dig up is [this question about where to post requests/reports](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285802/359284), which I answered a while back. It has quite a few links that point to places where SE devs have made it clear that it doesn't matter where.