# When down voting with less than 125 rep

Tags: discussion, downvotes

So if you vote down with less than 125 rep then SO tells you it is recorded but not publicly shown. Does that affect bounty outcome? In an bounty question (500) a user answered the following

> I shoved this into my sandbox blog to see what the issue could be and it's a forehead slapper when I checked the JS console.
>   {block:Date},date:
>   Remove the comma before date and it should work. Let me know if you have more questions.

This did not answer the question and as it ties with my question for the votes and is low quality if I down vote will that affect the auto give for bounty? (I have less than 125 rep)
[How do I add JavaScript to every non-index page on my Tumblr blog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839282/how-do-i-add-javascript-to-every-non-index-page-on-my-tumblr-blog/38985966)

EDIT: I would never down vote just to get the rep bonus from bounty auto award.

Comment: Aaaand meta effect has ensured you won't be getting the bounty. Lol. Never link to stuff you don't want critiqued to death on meta.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326060/1169519).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, "feedback" doesn't count, since it doesn't affect the score of the post. The feedback doesn't do anything within the system; but it can be analyzed using [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/323179).

Note that none of the answers are currently eligible for automatic bounty points, since they all score 0 or less:

> the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount - [What is a bounty?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Even since it says it was recorded?

Comment: @ChristopherPeart It was recorded somewhere, but it doesn't change the score of the post. (Ha, I found it and edited it in my answer in time to still edit this comment.)

Comment: Are "feedback" votes do anything other than make the voter feel better?

Comment: @Goose iirc, feedback votes are calculated into some of the site-wide stats.

Comment: I think the answer is no @Goose, otherwise one could set up sock puppets. But it lets new users train their judgement without feeling rejected by the site.

Comment: If you downvote something before you reach 125 rep, does the vote become real if you pass 125?

Comment: @OscarSmith A lot of people seem to believe that, but no. That is not the case.

Comment: Why not? It seems we should at least give users a list of things they have down-voted for them to review and downvote if appropriate once they are able to.

Comment: @OscarSmith The number of people below 125 reputation who aren't help-vampires and actually regularly contribute to the community (by voting, flagging, commenting, answering) is probably very small, because those people will very quickly get above 125 reputation. It is likely just a waste of time for the developers to create a function like that. Furthermore, it takes a while to "learn" how to judge posts here, both according to the site rules, and according to what the community thinks is right. I can confidently say that my judgement back then was very bad, and my votes weren't accurate.

Comment: @Gendarme help-vampire... i like that. should be a tag for sure

Comment: @OscarSmith Because downvoting can subtract reputation, and make you go below 125 again. So maybe not all downvotes could become real, so StackOverflow should either choose some downvotes with some criteria, or wait until there is enough reputation to downvote them all. But then people would complain they are stuck at 125 for a while, or that they had a sudden big decrease of reputation. So it's not that simple.