# What does it mean when it says my vote is "recorded" but "does not change the publicly displayed posted score"?

Tags: support, voting

I have less than 125 reputation, and when I upvote and then downvote the same post, this message pops up:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed posted score.

What does it mean when it says my votes are 'recorded'? 
Thanks to [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re/326090), I know that it doesn't mean my votes will count once my reputation goes above 125. As far as I can tell right now, it seems to only change the displayed score on my screen and do nothing else, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I always assumed it meant that it was recorded so when I earned my 125 reputation, my votes will automatically be counted and modify the shown score retroactively. Apparently, I was wrong.

Comment: See this related question on how to view recorded but not displayed votes on a post: *[Where can I find the amount of up & down votes that are recorded but not publicly visible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375613/584192)*

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It means there's a record in the database that a vote was cast by some user without the privilege to cast a vote. It has no other meaning.

For those who care, this information can be queried using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), as it is exposed publicly (in anonymized form) as part of the weekly data dumps.

Since all of the information is collected and stored, it would be technically possible for some system process to begin using it at some point in the future. However, there are no automated processes that consider this data, and it has yet to be used for anything over the many years that the information has been collected.

Comment: *"it has yet to be used for anything over the many years that the information has been collected."* ... I'm sure such data has been utilized by Stack Exchange on many occasions.

Comment: @TinyGiant I was referring to the system itself.  No site mechanisms have been built off of it.  It's quite possible that individual employees have looked at the data and used it to make decisions about...things.

Comment: That's fair, but the statement is still a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you start reading at "it has yet [...]" then yes, that would be ambiguous, but given that the sentence starts out with "it would be possible for this information to be used by some **system process**" it seems pretty clear that that's what it's referring to.

Comment: I disagree, it seems like you're saying [paraphrased] "The system could use this data at some point in the future, but it has yet to be used for anything yet" which seems to me to imply that the data has yet to be used at all. This was the immediate impression when I first read the post, and it still is every time I re-read it.

Comment: You love birds need to lighten up.  The gist of it is the data's there but not being currently used on the actual site (outside of the data explorer that probably more than 90% of the folks on this site dont even use).  Stop making it so difficult - this isn't English class!

Comment: I always thought such data went into [this dataset](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback)…

Comment: @Paulie_D The data has been recorded, but has yet to be used by some system process. :P

Comment: So, nitpicking aside: has anyone actually used the non-votes data for anything substantive?

Comment: Afaik, it's being used for the "Greatest hits" page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits (what is useful that page for... is anyone guess)

Comment: Is there a way to find this data myself, I now got the association bonus and would like to upvote all the answers that I wasn't able to before.

Comment: @Ajay You can't find what you voted on.  You can see the vote totals for each post.  The (public) data is anonymized.

Comment: That's really weird why bother saying my vote was "recorded" if it literally has no meaning and there's literally no way to observe it. If the system wants to keep it for possible future use then fine but no point telling me (the user) that??

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Others can observe *that* the post was voted on, just not by whom.

Comment: Only by delving into the database, according to your answer. The UI shouldn't give hints that are only relevant for people delving into the database, but instead for people using the UI

Comment: I'm not saying it's a useful feature or that it should be designed the way that it is.  This post is merely explaining how it works.  Your claim that it's literally unobservable is false.  It's observable, just obscure enough that few bother to look at it.  If you want the feature to be designed differently then post a feature request with your proposed change, rather than complaining on a post explaining how it works by saying that it behaves differently than it actually does.

Comment: Well that's a pity. Always thought they'd kind of combine those votes, like e.g. 100 of these votes equal one real vote that gets shown and that way a question many users have, no matter how skilled or how much rep., would still go up a bit.    Maybe they'll implement that at some point.

Comment: @Servy like Bergi commented, there's [this dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback) which shows "Registered Feedback". Isn't it exactly the thing discussed here?

Answer (score -2):

The issue could also be resolved if there was an option to down-vote privately, just so that if you encounter the same post in the future, you don't waste time reading it. This way, even low-ranking users can down-vote as much as they like and only after they have enough rep, be able to change it to a public down-vote if they so desire.

The same way bookmarking is a private affair of keeping tabs on good posts.

Comment: "The issue could also be resolved" - **what issue**?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, this is already exactly what happens for low-rep users: The vote is recorded privately but it does not count unless one later does a proper downvote. What are you suggesting to happen differently?

Comment: For the user to actually see their own down-votes, not just mods

Comment: The answer doesn’t actually say one would see these downvotes. You might want to [edit] the answer to spell that out since it seems to be *the* change but right now must be inferred.

Comment: Since server-side support wouldn't be essential, I think I'll just make a Chrome extension for it when I get the time... Such suggestions usually fall onto deaf ears here :)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood. My claim is that "users who don't have the privilege to downvote can't see their 'downvotes'" - because they are **not actually downvotes** - is **not an issue**, and therefore does not require resolving.

Comment: Just to be clear: on any site with a voting mechanism (not just Stack Exchange), the purpose of downvotes **is not** for the server to remember the downvoter's personal notes, but to **rate content collaboratively** with other users who vote. Just like, you know, real-world voting in elections.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to say this, but I actually like the way YouTube got rid of down-votes since they were quite misleading. And as you mentioned, just like actual elections, down-votes do not translate well into real life. Furthermore, you must have noticed how even StackExchange is moving towards a more intelligent sorting of answers rather than simple vote-count based. So, it could essentially get rid of down-votes altogether just like YT and make it a totally private matter, but that would be a too bold suggestion I did not dare propose :)