# Where can I find the amount of up & down votes that are recorded but not publicly visible?

Tags: support, downvotes, voting, upvotes, anonymous-user

I made a question that got some votes, but I still don't know if there are more that are **not publicly visible** on the question page from users without enough reputation.

Users without enough reputation will see a message like this when attempting to vote, which **suggests that the up/down votes are recorded somewhere**:

[image]

How can I find records of these votes, if this is even possible?

Comment: Feedback votes like these are recorded but aren't actually used anywhere. Things like post bans and badges are only affected by "real" votes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [Shog9's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have/259591#comment846183_259591) on Meta Stack Exchange in response to "the feedback is actually recorded?",

> Yes, yes it is. You can even find it recorded in the data dump and SEDE within the PostFeedback table. 
> -– Shog9 ♦ Jun 27 '15 at 17:22

The only way to retrieve the non-public votes by users without the vote-up/vote-down privileges or anonymous votes, is via a SEDE query.

For example, for your question [Nothing appears when drag-and-dropping anything from the Palette in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117574/nothing-appears-when-drag-and-dropping-anything-from-the-palette-in-android-stud), this query would display an anonymous upvote on your post:

**https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/914399/?postid=52117574**

You'll want to focus on these vote types:

[image]

SEDE is updated weekly, so the votes *may not be current*.

Answer (score 11):

As Samuel shared in his answer, the votes are recorded in SEDE.

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/889727/my-most-insufficient-rep-voted-posts). It creates an overview of score and post feedback on your questions, sorted by the amount of post feedback votes, so you can view feedback directed to you and discrepancies between feedback and score.

There are also pages on-site that report this data.

One example of such a page is the [greatest hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) page. Below the tags, the feedback score can be seen.

IIRC there are more than that single one, but I can't find them atm.

Answer (score 6):

*I misunderstood your question earlier (before the edit), and thought you wanted to view vote counts on a post without having the required reputation privilege to do so. However, I'm leaving this incorrect answer up as it still contains useful information.*

---

1. If you can install a userscript, you can use this userscript I made to fetch vote counts via the API, and you can do so again as many times as you wish: [FetchVoteCountsAgain](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#fetch-vote-counts-again). For those with the privilege, it uses the `/vote-counts` endpoint instead of the API (while still respecting the 1s rate limit)
2. If you don't want to use a userscript, you could also ask in the comments for someone to fetch the current count for you, although I wouldn't recommend this.
3. Alternatively, you can view daily vote changes on your own posts by visiting the post timeline page `/posts/{post-id}/timeline` - this however, only updates daily and you won't be able to view the day's vote summary before the first time it records an entry.
4. You can go through [your own reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=time) and count the votes up to the day your question was posted. +5 are upvotes, and -2 are downvotes.
5. Finally, you can also load [your reputation audit page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), find the post's ID on the page, and count the corresponding votes using the same method described above (+5 : upvote, -2 : downvote)

Comment: FYI: The votes entry (i.e. the "daily summary") in the timeline that's labeled "today" is live. It updates as soon as an up-/down-vote is cast (and you reload the timeline page). If the entry doesn't exist, then nobody has voted in this UTC day. Timeline pages are publicly available for all non-deleted posts (i.e. you can view them when not logged-in). In other words, the OP can view votes this way on any non-deleted post, not just their own. They should also be able to view the timeline for their own deleted posts.