# Upvoting/Downvoting a post - wrong translation?

Tags: bug

The **header** saying "*Thanks for the feedback!*" when you upvote/downvote a question whilst not being logged in feels out of place. We're not providing any feedback, something like "You must be logged in to do this!" would be better.

[image: translation-mismatch]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

But you are providing feedback. It's not displayed on the post's score, but it *is* tracked.  [You can see the results yourself if you want to query it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375619/1159478)

Comment: I would still alter the text somewhat to make it more obvious/transparant: "This action requires 15 reputation to be public, but we're still tracking it internally" would prevent this question from being asked again (in theory).

Comment: If you're not aware of the functionality, it looks like a problem. And no amount of Googling or searching on existing bugs is going to help you find it.

Comment: "If you're not aware of the functionality, it looks like a problem." That is true of most features of this site, from duplicate closure to voting to flags, etc. It's actually true of... most things as well? If you're not aware that the metro will be moving after the doors close, a helpless person can find it's a problem they get somewhere else. I don't think it's a valid argument @Zarthus.