# How do I check my past upmod (pre-upvote-privilege) upvoted answers?

Tags: support, upvotes, privileges

I have a repeated issue and I have to find an answer which I marked as helpful (upvoted).

My upvote activity shows nothing under this link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=upvote .

How can I view my upvotes prior to having the privilege?

My reputation is below 15, so I don't have upvote privileges. However, the tooltip says that the site records my feedback but won't show it. How do I view that activity (my upvotes) to find that answer again?

Comment: The anonymised form of PostFeedback is accessible through SEDE though that doesn't help you determine what you gave feedback on. Presumably there's a complete record somewhere, but that would probably require a staff member to access and provide. I'm not aware of anywhere within a user profile that this information is available.

Comment: In future, you might find the "saves" feature more useful for bookmarking useful posts, as it has some capability for categorisation.

Comment: Do you remember how you found the answer? If if it was through a google or bing search, the search might still be in your browser history so you could maybe find it back that way. You'd have to find search keywords in the url which match your repeating issue description.

Comment: See also [Where can I find the amount of up & down votes that are recorded but not publicly visible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375613/where-can-i-find-the-amount-of-up-down-votes-that-are-recorded-but-not-publicl). It's from a different point of view, bt it's still related

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Stack Overflow website does not provide any way to find which questions you upvoted before you had the privilege to upvote.  Sorry.  You'll have to find some other way to locate that answer.