# Why not showing the downvotes of an answers?

Tags: feature-request

Then people can also see "the downside" of the answer to think about whether is has some side effect, not well explained part(s). This also saves the time reading some vague comments below the answer like:

"No, this answer is not correct, Blablablah"

"I don't agree the part you said, Blablablah"

I have read several old posts with 100+ more upvotes with this kind of comments below it, then when I ask them for details, no reply at most of the cases. Nobody care it. (Because the commenter has already "left" this site)

This kind of comments always let me don't want to read the answer, even with high upvotes.

Comment: You have some pretty terrible justification for why separating votes is a good idea. You should read the post and then you can decide if the comment is valid. I don't see how knowing the number of downvotes indicates the validity of a negative comment at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have 1000 reputation, you are considered an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). You can then see individual vote counts (both upvotes and downvotes).

Why 1000 rep you ask?
Because it is [expensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/258356), in terms of running the query, to view the vote count.

Comment: So stackoverflow is not for new user. It's a secret community for experts only.

Comment: Not really. You can still downvote, which is considered as it should be. It is just that one doesn't get to see the individual counts until they score at least 100 rep points and earn the priviledge

Comment: I remember some message says "your rep. below 125 blablablah, we will take your votes into consideration" but I believe the action is ignored if I'm the designer of this site.

Comment: I mean 1000 rep points in the above comment.

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I understand it.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327213/: "_votes from anyone who hasn't yet earned the up-vote or down-vote privileges are available for your analysis in the regular public data dumps and [via Data Explorer in the PostFeedback table](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/506897)._"

Comment: @Cœur: Lol, I thought that was a joke.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 We never make a joke here on meta.

Comment: @TGrif: No I didn't say the comment is a joke, I meant the message shown when voting under 125 rep. on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have 1k rep, you can view vote counts, as mentioned in [Help Center Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), so you earn it simply click on the vote score, then you'll see the number of up-votes and down-votes.

Usually, for under 1k rep users, when you put your mouse on the vote score, it would be regular cursor for text, but for users with over 1k rep, it would be a cursor that's meant for clicking on stuff, if you look at the link above in this answer, you'll understand it better.

Comment: But I'm still correct that truth is privileged.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 Yeah that's true

Comment: Open source means open only the part I want you to know.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 StackOverflow never claimed to be "open source," as if that term even applies to a community.