# Is Meta suitable for SE platform questions?

Tags: support, meta

I have a few questions about the general functionality of the platform for the Stack Exchange web of sites, Stack Overflow included. Of a technical/support kind.

While I have had searched for answers for those already, my google-fu has failed.

So, my question is: Is Stack Overflow meta a suitable place for such questions, or should I ask for answers elsewhere?

If it's not, I'll greatly appreciate pointing me into right direction for such enquiries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are welcome to [ask on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them), but there is a network wide meta site.  You can find it at https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Aha, thanks. Hadn't thought of this somehow.
I'll return to your answer after I explore "global" meta site

Comment: Your advice to look at http://meta.stackexchange.com turns out to be really usefull. I've already found some answers. Thanks, once again