# Where to ask the simplest programming questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a website where I could ask some fundamental questions on computer programming?

To make myself more clear, I desire to increase my proficiency in C# specifically. But when I consult books, it seems the books are too elementary or too theoretical and does not teach me practical real-life type examples that I can further use to improve my proficiency.

Hence, I feel that if such questions are asked on Stack Overflow, some of its experts feel such simple questions, too broad with many answers, ought not be asked on Stack Overflow. Hence if I am able to ask such simple questions on a website, those with time will respond in a real-world scenario, and that helps greatly a beginner type programmer.

Comment: Super-User. This question should be asked on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) though, not here.

Comment: Specifically on C# related doubts?

Comment: Not too sure about that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all your doubts are already answered on SO, you need to be asking how you search for the answers IMO.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Stack Overflow isn't meant to replace beginners books.

Comment: SO isn't just for complex questions, simple questions are fine too. **However, the simpler the question, the more you need to ensure the question is 1) very well asked, 2) not trivially answered by the manual, 3) not something that would better be replaced by a structured tutorial/course/book.**

Comment: @Seth why should this question be asked on MSE?

Comment: @rene Because it's asking for a [site recommendation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)?..

Comment: Those are on-topic here as well, as long as there is doubt if something is on-topic on SO. So don't ask where to ask to make Christmas Pudding...

Comment: @rene The wording doesn't really make it seem like it's asking "Is this on-topic for SO", but rather "Where can I ask this?".

Comment: @Seth with a bit of editing it does ...

Comment: @Seth generally speaking, if it is on-topic for MSE, it is on-topic here. Please read [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Comment: Instead of asking this question, just ask your actual question already(after searching and finding such a question doesn't already exist, that is). If you get a relevant answer, great!. If not, you'll know. But most times, you'll at least get a suggestion where to get further helpful info.

Comment: Do you mean here on Meta @HarshKanchina or on the main site. Because on main this can have bad consequences if the question is met with down and close votes.

Comment: On the main site @rene . Down and close votes could be avoided if the question has been properly searched for duplicates prior to asking, which is what I mentioned the OP should be doing before posting.

Comment: @HarshKanchina most users think that stating *I searched for hours* would be enough to indicate they did their research. However, the results found and their interpretation should be part of the question because that enables us to elaborate, starting at the very spot the knowledge of the OP ended. For questions that simply lack the info to make a judgement on where the OP is stuck shouldn't be posted, instead should be held against the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). If such questions still get posted there cannot be enough down and close votes to get rid of it quickly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Programming questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow, regardless of their simplicity.
But two things to keep in mind:

1. Stack Overflow has been running for many years. The simple questions have probably already been asked and answered—perhaps many times! Search thoroughly, using both the site search feature and Google, along with various combinations of keywords, *before asking* to make sure that you are not asking a question that has already been covered.
2. Beginners often have extremely *broad* questions. These are explicitly *off-topic* for Stack Overflow. Anything that cannot be reasonably answered in a few paragraphs is not a suitable question. You should instead consider taking a course, buying a book, or reading a tutorial. A Q&A website is not a good way to learn programming if you have absolutely no background.
3. Even if you manage to come up with a narrowly-scoped question that is not a duplicate, and you ask it well (nicely formatted, proper spelling/grammar, etc.), be prepared to get some downvotes. There are inevitably users here who do not like such questions, and would prefer that you simply consulted the manual. So, you know, you might want to do that first before asking. Or just take your downvotes with pride.

Comment: Don't forget [tag-wiki's](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) and [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)...

Comment: I'm trying very hard to forget Documentation, @rene.

Comment: I do relevant data processing in my office works with C# which I mostly taught myself without undergoing any structured course or book. In earlier days I was using FoxPro which acted as a barrier on picking up OOP skills. But I can process data in C#. My doubts arise when I explore newer aspects of C#. In a way Cody Gray's answer is very interesting to me. I think there is no website exclusively devoted to simplest questions.

Comment: No, there is not going to be a website dedicated exclusively to "simple" questions. Not for free, at least. How would you find enough experts willing to answer them? Stack Overflow works because it has a balance.

Comment: OK.. @Cody Gray

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Consider that one of the goals of SO is *deduplication.* There isn't enough time in the world for experts to teach everything to non-experts one-by-one. To some degree it is a must that questions are posed exactly once and canonically answered exactly once. The likelihood that a *basic* questions has already been answered in a book somewhere is exceedingly high. Be respectful of people's time and consult such resources first. Or pay someone for their time to mentor you personally.

Comment: I do respect other people's time. Time is invaluable.

Comment: Rene's recommended documentation sites looks extremely useful. @rene

Comment: You're going out of your way to advocate that people ask questions that the site specifically indicates it doesn't want (poorly researched content already readily accessible) and telling people to be proud of harming the community?

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret your comment, @servy. Nowhere in this answer do I advocate people asking poorly researched questions. Perhaps you are adopting an excessively literal interpretation of the last sentence?

Comment: @CodyGray So you're saying that if you ask a low quality, poorly researched question, you should expect downvotes because people just don't like them (rather than saying that they're explicitly considered not acceptable, and that downvotes *exist* to indicate that a question is poorly researched; it's their *intended purpose* to indicate that) and then just telling people to proud of their downvotes.

Comment: I think I did not commit any crime in asking 'where I can I simplest programming doubts?" But the question has evoked such brute response from a section of the experts (I respect them) seems amazing to me!

Comment: Con'td from the previous comment. I am a person belonging to a third-world country. But now it seems to me that if such a web site for raising questions had existed in our own country, our people would have dealt with in a very different and helpful way rather than blocking the attempt to raise the question itself.

Comment: Cont'd from previous comment. You can just imagine that most of the people around the world are very poor and giving them a helping hand is one of the nicest things that as human beings we should do. If there are people who have time at their disposal, they can answer. Those without time will simply ignore it. I don't understand this sort of argument that was raised to block raising question on website. I am absolutely sorry that there does not exist a website by illiterate people for illiterates! I don't mean any bad things to anyone. "Vasudhaiva Kutumbakam" means Word is one family.

Comment: World is one family.

Comment: @Servy There's a disconnect here; you are interpreting my answer very differently than I do. The question and my answer are both about *simple* questions, which are not the same as *stupid* questions, even though they both start with the same letter. Low-quality, stupid, poorly-researched questions are categorically bad, no matter what level of sophistication they come from. I don't think that is true of *all* simple/beginner questions. We have lots of perfectly valid questions that I think are very simple and basic. But they've helped a great many people, and violate no rules.

Comment: Or maybe the core disagreement is simply that you *do* think simple/beginner questions are always off-topic. That's fine, you're entitled to that opinion, and you have the right to downvote questions on that basis. In fact, this was why I pointed out that some users *do* have this opinion, and that they will voice that opinion via downvotes, thus asking simple questions may net you downvotes. But note that this hatred of simple/beginner questions is *not* site policy, and never was. Reading into Unikrishnan's inquiry an implicit "low-quality" adjective is not fair.