# Stack Exchange arithmetic overflow error

Tags: support, data-explorer

If you run the below query on data.stackexchange.com, it gives an arithmetic overflow error which should not happen ideally.

```
select avg(viewcount) as average from posts
```

Comment: [Users can report bugs on whatever child meta site suits them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them) - don't arbitrarily close this because it's not explicitly a StackOverflow question

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered [casting it to a float instead](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714611)?

Comment: Have you considered dropping that and trying jQuery?

Comment: @CodyGray:  If you can get jQuery to execute SQL I will give you literally all of the internets.  *Right* after I pwn the database, of course. ;)

Comment: There is something that jQuery cannot do?  :)

Comment: You laugh, [but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234056/can-we-execute-sql-queries-in-jquery)...

Comment: @CodyGray:  Anyone can leave a REST endpoint insecure.  I was talking proper SQL statements.  But yeah...I think I'll leave it there. :P

Comment: BIGINT also works http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/715574