# What is this gray rectangle on the Stack Exchange profile page?

Tags: discussion, support, design, profile-page

I am just curious of what that gray blank space signifies and why is it there as is? Do I need some privileges to see the content inside that or its just as is, but why? Just curious!

[image]

Comment: That's the SE network account page.  This is off topic here, belongs on [metase].

Comment: [Users can report bugs on whatever child meta site suits them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them) - Don't close a question just because you think it belongs on another meta site.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, (1) this is not a bug. (2) the question issue is not an SO thing, nor is it network-wide. It applies only to the network account page. (3) from the MSE blog/announcement: "**When in doubt, you can always post your question on your local meta. If it’s clearly relevant to the engine or network as a whole, we’ll move it.**".  So clearly this is off topic here and should be migrated. The first step is closing it (absent a moderator).

Comment: @BrockAdams From Tim's question post: "If Stack Overflow participants are more comfortable reporting bugs **or asking for features here**, worry more about engaging them in discussion or support than what bucket might fit their question best." and from Shog's answer post: "we can and do have tooling to track bugs across the entire network **without the need for unproductive migration**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @BrockAdams The intent of the linked post is to give direction that migration is not necessary, regardless of the type of question.  In fact, the **2nd sentence** in Tim's post is this (emphasis his): "**It's fine if users post bug reports, requests for support or feature requests here on MSO, there's no need to close them as off-topic. Please, don't do that, it's off-putting and rude.**" This Q *is a support request*, this *site is MSO*, and closing as off-topic still has the effect that Tim is specifically saying to avoid.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, Tim was talking about site-wide stuff.  This is not. Rather than being something that applies to Stack Overflow, plus a bunch of other sites, **it doesn't apply to Stack Overflow at all**.  It applies to one specific corner of the SE network.  Clearly the purview of MSE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's your "About me". It's currently empty.

If you click the *"Update profile info"* link at the bottom of that block, you can copy the "About me" from one of your profiles to your network profile.

Comment: aah -- ohkay now I got!! That's little bit weird design approach though ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I just updated it, and now there is no way to clear it!!?

Comment: @KaranDesai: you can clear your profile on one of the sites, then copy that empty profile to the network account. Not sure why you'd do that, of course.

Comment: That worked too..That was quiet intriguing \_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Here, you dropped this ¯\, @KaranDesai.

Comment: @KaranDesai  what do you mean "_(ツ)_/¯ –"?

Comment: @McMillanCheng That is a [shrug emoticon](https://www.reddit.com/r/shrug/comments/73g30t/%E3%83%84/?st=jayb182x&sh=6d112cf7), albeit with a missing arm.

Comment: @1blustone  Good to know that..   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  thanks.  :D

Comment: Haha yeah..That was a modified version of shrug emoticon :) I actually meant this: http://static.skaip.org/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/whew.gif