# Russian stackoverflow site logo chopped when looking at a user profile

Tags: bug

It only happens when looking at a user profile:

[image]

PS: Don't ask me why I was on the russian site, I just happened to notice it.

Comment: Perhaps MSE/Meta.ru.so would be a more appropriate place for this report, since it doesn't affect normal SO.

Comment: Report on [meta.se]: [Site name gets cropped while looking at user profiles on international Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316661)

Comment: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)